# Mathjax CDN is shutting down effective April 30th 2017

Tags: support, mathjax

If you haven't seen the [official announcement](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/) yet, Mathjax is shutting down their CDN effective April 30th 2017.  We are currently looking for alternatives for hosting this service including self hosting.  I wanted to make everyone aware that they may see a switch in the location where Mathjax is hosted.

Comment: What is the effect of this shutdown on MO ? Will the mathematical symbols and formulas still be properly displayed ?

Comment: @ToddLeason: As I read the post, yes math notation will be properly displayed. The only difference from the user's standpoint is the where the service is hosted. Worst case: pages will load a little slower. (But they might be faster. It all depends on the new host.)

Comment: Geoff, Jon, thanks for the information.